# Is strict aliasing only for the first element?

Tags: c, gcc, casting, simd

Using GCC 4.7.2, why does this cause a strict alias violation:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "emmintrin.h"

int f(){
    int ret = 0;

    __m128i vec_zero __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
    __m128i vec_one __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = _mm_set1_epi32(1);
    __m128i vec_result __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
    vec_result = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(vec_zero, vec_one);
    ret += (((uint32_t*)&vec_result)[0] != 0); 
    ret += (((uint32_t*)&vec_result)[1] != 0); 
    return ret;
}
```

While this is ok:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "emmintrin.h"

int f(){
    int ret = 0;

    __m128i vec_zero __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
    __m128i vec_one __attribute__ ((aligned (16))) = _mm_set1_epi32(1);
    __m128i vec_result __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));
    vec_result = _mm_cmpgt_epi32(vec_zero, vec_one);
//    ret += (((uint32_t*)&vec_result)[0] != 0); 
    ret += (((uint32_t*)&vec_result)[1] != 0); 
    return ret;
}
```

Is this simply an issue of gcc not being accurate or am I missing something about how strict aliasing works.

Also, is there a simple way around this with the use of `__attribute__((__may_alias__))` or am I just as well off casting to a temp char*?

Comment: `__attribute__ ((aligned (16)))` seems useless.

Comment: @MarcGlisse why do you say that? I thought the arguments to `_mm_cmpgt_epi32` have to be aligned.

Comment: `__m128i` already implies a suitable alignment (otherwise it would be really painful to use).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's just a failure of GCC to catch the problem. It's certainly UB (aliasing violation). Solving it with `__attribute__((__may_alias__))` is easy though:

```
typedef uint32_t __attribute__((__may_alias__)) u32ma;
```

then use `u32ma` instead of `uint32_t` in the pointer cast.